# Find the Recurrence relation for $q_n$ given the following condition:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $q_n$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ (formed from digits 0,1,2,3) which have even number of $2$'s. set up a recurrence relation for $q_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it can be defined by two recurrence. Suppose $p_n$ is the number of strings which have odd 2's. Now we have:
$$q_n = 3q_{n-1} + p_{n-1}$$
$$p_n =  q_{n-1}        + 3 p_{n-1}$$

Now we can unified them by matrix operation by $T_n = \begin{bmatrix}q_n \\  p_n \end{bmatrix}$:

$$T_n=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}T_{n-1}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 \end{bmatrix}T_{n-1}=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}T_{n-1}.$$

Now we can say $T_n = \begin{bmatrix}q_n \\  p_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{n-1}T_1$. We can compute that $T_1 = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\  1 \end{bmatrix}$, and 
$$T_n = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}3 \\  1 \end{bmatrix}$$